# List files in folder sub-directory

Tags: php, jquery

I have a script that when clients create a pdf file, it is placed in a folder named with there own code. This is in a main folder called '**destcerts**' and the folder structure ends up looking like the illustration below. What I need to do as admin is have access to these files and the only way I can do that at the moment is to hard code the sub-directory in the code and that is not practical for obvious reasons.

What I thought I could do is, have a select dropdown with a list of clients which when selected could trigger perhaps a change event which would say loop for the chosen client and display the files. Unfortunately, my php or jquery is not good enough to achieve this and I would be grateful if someone could show me the way to go forward with this. Many thanks

php code

```
<div id="viewCerts" style="display:none;">
      <?php
        $sub = 'destcerts/';

        // READ THE NAMES OF FILES IN THE SUB-DIRECTORY
        $fff = new DirectoryIterator($sub);
        $sss = array();

        foreach ($fff as $filedata)
        {
        // SKIP THE "DOT" FILES
        if ($filedata->isDot()) continue;

        // ACTIVATE THIS LINE TO RESTRICT IT TO PDF FILES ONLY
        if ($filedata->getExtension() != 'pdf') continue;


        // CREATE LINKS TO THESE FILES
        $nom = $filedata->getFilename();

        $lnk
        = '<img src="destcerts/PDF_icon_100.png" style="margin-bottom: 15px; margin-top:15px;"><br /><a href="'
        . $sub
        . '/'
        . $nom
        . '" style="color:#0099FF; text-decoration:none; font-size:12px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">'
        . $nom
        . '</a>'
        ;


        // COLLECT THE LINKS HERE
        $sss[] = $lnk;

        }

        // ACCUMULATE THE TABLE ROWS HERE
        $trs   = NULL;

        // COLLECT GROUPS OF FOUR
        If(!empty($sss)){
        while (!empty($sss))
        {
        $td1 = array_shift($sss) or NULL;
        $td2 = array_shift($sss) or NULL;
        $td3 = array_shift($sss) or NULL;
        $td4 = array_shift($sss) or NULL;

        // USE HEREDOC TO INSERT THESE INTO A TABLE ROW
        $tr  = <<<EOD
        <tr>
        <td align="center" width="20%" style="padding-bottom:20px !important;">$td1</td>
        <td align="center" width="20%" style="padding-bottom:20px !important;">$td2</td>
        <td align="center" width="20%" style="padding-bottom:20px !important;">$td3</td>
        <td align="center" width="20%" style="padding-bottom:20px !important;">$td4</td>
        </tr>
EOD;

        // APPEND THE TABLE ROW TO THE OTHER ROWS
        $trs .= $tr;
        }
        }
        else{

        $msg = "There are no files to display";

        $tr  = <<<EOD
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center; padding: 10px !important; font-weight: normal;">$msg</td>
        </tr>
EOD;

        $trs .= $tr;
        }

        // USE HEREDOC TO INSERT THE TABLE ROWS INTO THE TABLE
        $tab = <<<EOD
        <table id="pdfDownload" width="97%" align="center" border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0" style="border:1px solid grey; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-bottom:20px;">
        <th style="text-align:center; padding: 10px !important; padding-bottom: 20px; border:1px solid black; background-color: #3399FF; color: white; font-size: 18px !important;" colspan="4">Destruction Certificates Download</th>
        <tr>
        <th></th>
        </tr>
        $trs
        </table>
EOD;

        // SHOW THE WORK PRODUCT
        echo $tab;
?>
</div>
```

directory structure

```
.
..
destcerts
  client1
  client2
  client3
  etc
```

Comment: can you add a sample of the expected HTML output?

Comment: @mTorres The output should be as above if I understand you correctly. The admin selects a client this then populates the html table with the files in the selected sub-directory. Have I understood you correctly? Thanks